# Linq Left join, where, group by, count()

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need help with doing a Left join in a linq statement. My T-sql query works as expected but I can't seem to get the wanted results from the Linq. I also realize that there are ton of questions like mine, but I can't seem to apply any of the solutions to my case.

Products table

```
+---+------------+-----------+
|   |transportID |  Type(int)|
+---+------------+-----------+
| 1 | 5          | 1         |
| 2 | 5          | 3         |
| 3 | 6          | 3         |
+---+------------+-----------+
```

Stores

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |Name        |Type1(string)|
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | Ho         | 1           |
| 2 | He         | 2           |
| 3 | Be         | 3           |
| 4 | Ke         | 4           |
| 5 | Fe         | 5           |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

My wanted result is

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |Type        |Count        |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | 1          | 1           |
| 2 | 2          | 0           |
| 3 | 3          | 1           |
| 4 | 4          | 0           |
| 5 | 5          | 0           |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

My tsql that works as intended

```
SELECT 
    Type1,
    Count(Pro.transportId) as Count

FROM dbo.stores as sto

left Join dbo.products as pro on (sto.Type1 = pro.Type AND pro.transportId=5)

Where Type1 is not null
  group by Type1
  ORDER BY Type1 * 1 ASC
```

My Linq attempt returns this.

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |Type        |Count        |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | 1          | 1           |
| 3 | 3          | 1           |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

Linq Statement.

```
var res =   (from sto in _context.Stores
                             join pro in _context.Products on sto.Type1 equals System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)pro.Type).Trim()
                             where pro.transportId == transportId
                             group pro by pro.Type1 into pt1
                             select new TypeTransportation()
                             {
                                 Type = pt1.Key, // Needs to be int
                                 Count = pt1.Count()
                             }).ToList();
```

I've tried doing some defaultifempty but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Change join to left join won't do the trick?

Comment: shouldn't third row in your expected output be `| 3 | 3          | 2` ??

Comment: there is no left join in linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Utsav, no because im only searching for one specific transportationId at a time. In this case 5. Therefore there is only 1 with Type 3.

Comment: @sagi, in the answer in that one, I cant seem to put my where clause after the " Join... into ps", it doesnt compile.

Comment: @user56567675 .. please check my update .. it's working file :)

Comment: @Moumit ok will try it out asap.

Answer (score 3):

Here is MSDN link "How to: Perform Left Outer Joins" with LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397895.aspx

You code should be like this:

```
        var res = (from sto in _context.Stores
               join pro in _context.Products on sto.Type1 equals System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)pro.Type).Trim() into grpJoin
               from product in grpJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where product.transportId == transportId
               group product by product.Type1 into pt1
               select new TypeTransportation()
               {
                   Type = pt1.Key, // Needs to be int
                   Count = pt1.Count()
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Wow** .. lastly i did it ..

```
      var transportId = 5;
      var res = from s in _context.Stores
                let Type = _context.Stores.Take(1).Select(x => s.Type1).Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault()
                group Type by Type into pt1
                select new TypeTransportation
                {
                    Type = pt1.Key, // Needs to be int
                    Count = _context.Products.Where(i => i.transportId == transportId && i.Type == pt1.Key).Count()
                };            

      foreach (var item in res)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item.Type + " " + item.Count);
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How?? in what situation?

Comment: @user56567675 Why you delete your comments? Anyway let me know what problem you faced in above query?

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it in query syntax, but using extension method syntax it will be

```
var products = new[]
{
    new {transportId = 5, Type = 1},
    new {transportId = 5, Type = 3},
    new {transportId = 6, Type = 3},
    new {transportId = 5, Type = 3},
    new {transportId = 5, Type = 5},
};

var stores = new[]
{
    new {Name = "Ho", Type1 = "1"},
    new {Name = "He", Type1 = "2"},
    new {Name = "Be", Type1 = "3"},
    new {Name = "Ke", Type1 = "4"},
    new {Name = "Fe", Type1 = "5"},
};

var transportId = 5;
var res = stores                    
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: products
            .Where(product =>
                product.transportId == transportId),
        innerKeySelector: product => product.Type,
        outerKeySelector: store => Int32.Parse(store.Type1),
        resultSelector: (store, storeProducts) =>
            new
            {
                StoreType = store.Type1,
                StoreName = store.Name,
                ProductsCount = storeProducts.Count()
            })
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Just replace `Int32.Parse` with appropriate sql function call for actual DbContext query code.

---

With query syntax this is probably the best I can propose:

```
var res =
    from store in stores
    join product in 
        (from prod in products where prod.transportId == transportId select prod)
        on store.Type1 equals product.Type.ToString() into storeProducts
    select new
    {
        StoreType = store.Type1,
        StoreName = store.Name,
        ProductsCount = storeProducts.Count()
    };
```

Comment: I've not been able to find a string to int equivalent that works with EF.

Comment: @user56567675 So just do it the opposite way, like in the original attempt (int to string).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to follow the *left join* pattern described in [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx). The only tricky part is the `pro.transportId=5` condition in

```
left Join dbo.products as pro on (sto.Type1 = pro.Type AND pro.transportId=5)
```

The important thing is to **not** include it as `where` clause **after** the join.

One possible way to handle it is like this:

```
var res = (from sto in _context.Stores
           join pro in _context.Products
           on new { sto.Type1, transportId } equals
              new { Type1 = pro.Type.ToString(), pro.transportId }
           into storeProducts
           from pro in storeProducts.DefaultIfEmpty()
           group sto by sto.Type1 into pt
           select new 
           {
               Type = pt.Key, // the string value, there is no way to convert it to int inside the SQL
               Count = pt.Count()
           }).AsEnumerable() // switch to LINQ to Objects context
           .Select(pt => new TypeTransportation()
           {
               Type = Convert.ToInt32(pt.Type), // do the conversion here
               Count = pt.Count()
           }).ToList();
```

or just apply it as `where` clause **before** the join:

```
var res = (from sto in _context.Stores
           join pro in _context.Products.Where(p => p.transportId == transportId)
           on sto.Type1 equals pro.Type.ToString()
           into storeProducts
           // the rest ... (same as in the first query)
```

Another detail to mention is that in order to make `LEFT JOIN` effectively apply, you need to group by the left table (`Stores` in your case) field (like in the original SQL query), thus ending up with a `string` key. If you wish to get the `int` key, there is no way to do it inside the db query, so you need to use a temporary projection, context switch and the final projection as shown above.

**UPDATE:** The last thing that I didn't realize initially is that the original SQL `Count(Pro.transportId)` is excluding `NULL`s from the right side of the join. So the final correct equivalent LINQ query is:

```
var res = (from sto in _context.Stores
           join pro in _context.MyProducts
           on new { sto.Type1, transportId } equals
              new { Type1 = pro.Type.ToString(), pro.transportId }
           into storeProducts
           from pro in storeProducts.DefaultIfEmpty()
           group new { sto, pro } by sto.Type1 into pt
           select new
           {
               Type = pt.Key,
               Count = pt.Sum(e => e.pro != null ? 1 : 0)
           })
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(pt => new TypeTransportation()
           {
               Type = Convert.ToInt32(pt.Type),
               Count = pt.Count
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: still didnt work, ended up with all the types, which is great, and the correct values for the types that existed. but the ones that were supposed to be 0 were all over the place, most were 1 others were some random value.

Comment: @user56567675 You are right, I've missed one detail. Try the updated answer (because I don't want to think what SQL is generated with the currently accepted answer).